# Get info from entity reference using PHP

Tags: entities

I'm trying to use PHP to get user IDs from an Entity Reference of users in a content type.

I have got as far as doing (where I actually get the NID from elsewhere):

```
$node = node_load(123);

$info = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_users');
```

But how do I get the IDs from `$info`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to get the `target_id` from each of the field values, which you can do by looping through `$info`:

```
$uids = array();
foreach ($info as $field_item) {
  // Entity reference fields store their data in the 'target_id' column
  $uids[] = $field_item['target_id'];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Clive, yes `%node` instead of `$node` was just a typo in my question - shift+5 vs shift+4 - edited my Q and your A accordingly. I tested this by doing `print (string)$field_item['target_id'];` and nothing was printed. However, checking `count($info)` confirms the data is in there. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a `print_r` of the output of `$info` in your question?

Comment: Agh - I'm an idiot - I had a spelling mistake in my `field_get_items(`. Your solution works perfectly. Thankyou.